# Laravel updateOrCreate inserts random duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My project is experiencing a peculiar issue.
I am using laravel 5.4 with MySQL.
I am inserting multiple records (30,60, etc) and seldom it inserts duplicate records. Eg-
while creating records from 1/1/2018 to 30/1/2018 ie it should be inserting 30 records. Sometimes it does insert 30 records, but often it inserts more than that. There might be few duplicate entries like on 5,6,7 then 21,22,23,24 etc.
I checked on Github regarding this issue, and few people did face this issue, few said this is because of "Race Conditions".
It is really because of Race conditions? Why does this duplication occur? And is there any way to prevent it, I would prefer not locking my Database because multiple people might be inserting at the same time. Suggestions appreciated.

```
`$sdata = [
'tenant_id'          => Helper::getTenantID(),
'branch_id'          => Helper::getBranchID(),
'user_id'            => Helper::getUserID(),
'service_request_id' => $serviceRequestID,
'amount'             => $netRate,
'notes'              => $notes,
'status'             => 'Pending',
];
Schedule::updateOrCreate($sdata);`
```

Comment: I think you are using multiple inserts in a batch. If you keep batch number `1, 2, 3 and so on` and `created_at, created_by` with the inserted rows then you will be able to identify exactly how many inserts have been performed in a single batch. Moreover, the `created_by` field will let you identify whether or not someone else tried to run the same job or not.

Comment: I am sure that it is a single request, i am creating 1 record at a time in a forloop. I do save the user id of the person who has created it, and all were same, with almost no created_at timestamp difference

Comment: Show your updateOrCreate statement and your migration. Without seeing the first group of parameters in that statement, there is no way to answer your question with confidence.

Comment: @RobFonseca Added Code.

Comment: Still hard to tell unfortunately. What is was looking for was possibly a Datetime field when you were inserting on unique dates. Adding the database migration for your table and the loop that does the bulk insert might be a better clue as to where the problem lies.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you, as of now instead of using updateOrCreate I am simply using insert($data). Things look good as of now. Maybe its a behavioral issue with updateOrCreate.